# What is the best way to express "clothes" regarded as a single starting with "This is"?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number

Look at this sentence: **This is my beautiful clothes.**

I think it is grammatically incorrect because "**clothes**" is always plural.

I know "**these are my beautiful clothes.**" is grammatically perfect. But it doesn't actually reflect what I want to say, for it might indicate that there's more than one article of clothing.

What is the best way to express **one article of clothing** starting with "**This is**" ?

Is **"This is my piece of clothes"** okay ?

Comment: One article of clothing is a garment.https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=garment&oq=garment&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.1674j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: This is my piece of clothing.  This is my article of clothing.

Comment: Typically you would either say "outfit" or else use the specific name for the particular piece of clothing.  For example, *This is my beautiful dress.  This is my elegant suit.*  Yes, you could say *garment* but it would sound pretty awkward.  Note, *outfit* is the whole ensemble -- top and bottom (possibly two pieces on top).

Comment: Does 'outfit' not include all the accessories; socks, shoes, cuff links, tie etc etc ?

Comment: Nigel, Jim and Aparente, you've all given answers to the question, even with examples and references, how come no actual answer I can vote on?

Comment: @Spagirl It could be because they feel it's not ethical to close-vote for 'ELL standard' and provide an 'answer' rather than an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you aren't set on the word clothes, I think garment can be used here.

This is my garment.